# Word builder with java coding

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to do the following but I am stuck
I am writing a code that will get input from the user 
If the user enter(V)
the the code randomly print one vowel
else if the user enter (C)
The code randomly print a consonant
and this should happen until the user has made a choice of 10 letters, after what the program give the user 2 minutes to form a work out of the ten letters he composed. 
Here is the code I started but and I am blank as for how to implement the whole idea. Thanks for help.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class randomLetters {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //I am creating two list: a list of consonant and a list of vowels

        String con= "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
        String vow = "aeiouy";
// Getting user input

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt the user to chose a vowel of a consonant
        System.out.print("Enter (V) for vowel and (C for consonnant)");
        String V_or_C =input.next();
        if(V_or_C.equals("V")) {
//generating either a vowel or a consonant based on the user choice
             String s = "";
             Random random = new Random();
             int randomLen = 1+random.nextInt(9);
             for (int i = 0; i < randomLen; i++) {
                 char c = con.charAt(random.nextInt(26));
                 s+=c;
                 System.out.println(s);

        } if(V_or_C.equals("C")) {
             Random random1 = new Random();
             int randomLen1 = 1+random1.nextInt(9);
             for (int i = 0; i < randomLen1; i++) {
                 char c = vow.charAt(random1.nextInt(26));
                 s+=c;
                 System.out.println(s);

        }


        }


    }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updating my answer, Do Yo want something like this :**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class randomLetters extends Thread {

    String con = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"; // constant
    String vow = "aeiouy"; // Vowel

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] option = new char[10]; // total characters available to player

    String word; // answer given by player after 2 minute
    static int score = 0; // player score
    static int round = 1; // round number
    Boolean startPlaing = true;

    @Override
    public void run() { // run method of thread

        // ---------------------------------------------------->
        // game loop
        gameLoop();
        // ---------------------------------------------------->

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { // Main function

        new randomLetters().start(); // start method calls run()
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------->
    // calculating score : change the score logic as per your game rule
    public void getScore(String word) {
        // using rule : Words are worth one point per letter, but a nine-letter
        // word is worth double; that is, 18 points.
        score = word.length();
        if (word.length() >= 9)
            score = 18;

    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------->

    // ---------------------------------------------------->
    private void gameLoop() {
        while (startPlaing) {

            System.out
                    .println("Round : "
                            + round
                            + " Score : "
                            + score
                            + "\n---------------------------------------------------->");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // Prompt the user to chose a vowel
                                            // of a
                // consonant
                System.out
                        .println("> Enter (V) for vowel and (C for consonnant)");

                String V_or_C = input.next();

                if (V_or_C.equalsIgnoreCase("V")) { // generating a random vowel
                    option[i] = vow.charAt(new Random().nextInt(vow.length()));

                    System.out.println(option[i]);

                }
                if (V_or_C.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) { // generating a random
                                                    // constant
                    option[i] = con.charAt(new Random().nextInt(con.length()));
                    System.out.println(option[i]);

                }

            }
            startPlaing = false;

            try {

                System.out.print("\nAvailable character : ");

                for (char i : option) { // printing the selected options
                    System.out.print(" [ " + i + " ]");
                }

                System.out.println("\n\nGame waiting for 2 minute");

                Thread.sleep(120000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 seconds 120
                                        // seconds = 2 minute

                System.out.println("\n Time up !! Enter your word :");

                word = input.next();

                if (check(word)) {

                    System.out.println("\nStrart next round (y/n): ");
                    String choice = input.next();
                    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                        System.out
                                .println("\nLets Start---------------------------------------------------->\n");
                        round += 1; // increment round

                        startPlaing = true;
                    } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                        startPlaing = false;

                        System.out
                                .println("\nGood Bye :\nYour score till now :"
                                        + score);

                    }

                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    // ---------------------------------------------------->

    // ----------------------Start of check
    // function----------------------------->
    // check function validate game rules like:
    // 1. word or answer is not empty
    // 2. word is in dictionary
    // 3. word should only comprise using characters available as option
    // add rules as per your understanding of game.
    public Boolean check(String s) {

        String[] dictionary = { "help", "permited", "elephant", "relationship",
                "ab", "cv", "az", "a", "v", "zzz", "aeiou", "aeioucv",
                "aeiouz", "aeio", "aeiouaeio", "aei", "oye" };
        // add
        // valid
        // words
        // to
        // this
        // dictionary

        System.out.println("\nYou entered : " + s);

        if (s.length() != 0) { // if user has entered something

            char[] word = s.toCharArray();

            // check if answer only include character available as option
            // ---START
            Boolean b = false;

            for (char a : word) {
                for (int j = 0; j < option.length; j++) {

                    /*
                     * System.out.println("matching :" + a + " with " +
                     * option[j] + "   " + (a != option[j]));
                     */// uncomment to see the comparison

                    if (a != option[j]) {
                        b = true;

                    } else {
                        b = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (b) {
                    System.out
                            .println("\n Wrong answer (Game exit) : Your answer include characters other than option available to you . \n Your score till now is : "
                                    + score);
                    return false;
                }

            }
            // check if answer only include character available as option ---END

            // --------------------START------------------------------->
            //
            // add your code here for rule saying only same number of character
            // should be used
            // example: if there is only one 'c' available in option then player
            // answer can have only one 'c'
            //
            // --------------------END------------------------------->

            // check if answer is a valid word from words available in
            // dictionary ---START
            boolean notInDictionary = true;
            for (String c : dictionary) {

                /*
                 * System.out.println("matching :" + s + " with " + c + "   " +
                 * c.equals(s));
                 */// uncomment to see the matching

                if (c.equals(s)) // if word is in dictionary
                {
                    notInDictionary = false;
                    getScore(c);

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (notInDictionary) {
                // enter your logic for this situation
                // Example rule that you can add :If a contestant tries a longer
                // word that is not in the programme's dictionaries, his or her
                // word is rejected, but his or her opponent may score the
                // points for its length by giving a shorter, valid word.
                System.out
                        .println("\nYour answer is not a valid word available in our dictionary \nscore :"
                                + score);
                return false;
            }

            // check if answer is a valid word from words available in
            // dictionary ---END

            return true;
        }
        // ---------------------------------------------------->
        // If no input is entered by user

        if (s.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("\nGame Exit as No input and your score is : "
                    + score);

            return false;
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------->

        return false;
    }

    // -------------------End of check------------------------------->
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 1.Take choice and generate 10 option.

[image]

> 2. If user enter wrong input (That is if user uses characters other then available to him as option).

[image]

> 3. If user given answer exist in the Dictionary of words available to us then calculate the score using the rule :

**Words are worth one point per letter, but a nine-letter word is worth double that is, 18 points.**

[image]

> 4. If player chose to continue playing go to next round and if player chose 'n'.

[image]

Game reference was taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_chiffres_et_des_lettres)
I have provided comments within the code so that you can update the game as per your requirements.

I hope this answer is close to what you were looking for :)
you can comment if any update is required.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers like `21` and `6`. Use `con.length()` and `vow.length()`.

Comment: Hello Abhi Thanks for your reply. What I meant by the program gives the user 2 minute is that when the user has finished chosing 10 letters

Comment: the clock is set for 2 minutes whithin which he most form a word out of the letters randomly generated

Comment: You can use a Thread class and call Thread.sleep(long millis) : 

Thread.sleep(120000);
 // 1000 milliseconds = 1 seconds 120  seconds = 2 minute

Comment: I have also updated my answer to include an example for thread.sleep(). Kindly check for the same. You can modify the functionality as per your need.

Comment: Thank you Abhi. Let me sent you a link so you understand what I am trying to implement. My first language is French and I think I am not translating well my idea. watch this video carefully you will understand.       https://youtu.be/m__gRNStKB0?t=185

Comment: hi @Gusto, I have updated my answer. Kindly execute the code and check if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hey Abbi it works just perfect! Thanks. Is there a way I can enlarge the capacity of the dictionary?

Comment: Hi @Gusto, If you want to  add more words to dictionary? you can download a [french or English](http://www.gwicks.net/dictionaries.htm) word dictionary and include them in array/ linked list/ any data structure of your choice. You can also add a text file and read words from that. It's all up to you i.e how large you want to scale your project. Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918587/how-to-find-a-word-in-large-word-list-vocabulary-with-descent-memory-consumpti). If my answer (code) worked for you, Kindly mark it as right answer or up vote it :)