# Maximum number of words you can add to android keyboard dictionary

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I want to add words to android keyboard dictionary programmatically.

1. Am I correct to assume that speech to text will for a certain word will improve if it is in dictionary
2. How many words can I add in dictionary 1000, 10,000 or 100,000, is there any offical limit around size of dictionary (in MB)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are right. If the system knows how the word is written correctly it will then match the spoken word more exactly. Otherwise it will search between the existing words and probably takes something wrong. But the algorithm is allready really strong and precise.
2. There is no exact number or limit (nothing published officially). It depends on the device storage. But I did a research and will provide it to you:

- [Way to store a large dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276641/way-to-store-a-large-dictionary-with-low-memory-footprint-fast-lookups-on-and)
- [How to achieve a little dictionary](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dictionary-size-method-in-java-with-examples/)

Hope that answers your questions a bit. Cheers! :)